# iOS TWTRComposer Request failed: unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, twitterkit

With the following code and a bunch of other variations I've tried, I always get an unauthorized error. I'm using **TwitterKit 3.0** using CocoaPods. I've got my plist setup, my twitter app configured, and code like this:

```
// In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"XX", consumerSecret:"YYY")

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    return Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}

// In response to a click
Twitter.sharedInstance().logIn { session, error in
    if session != nil { // Log in succeeded
        let composer = TWTRComposer()

        composer.setText(tweetText)

        composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { result in
            if (result == .done) {
                print("Successfully composed Tweet")
            } else {
                print("Cancelled composing")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> "Did encounter error sending Tweet: Error
>   Domain=TWTRNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed:
>   unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=,
>   TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=401,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)"

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm getting the exact same problem! So frustrating.

Comment: I am having same problem. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't work even after following Twitter's setup instructions, try regenerating the consumer keys. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to log in when using `TWTRComposer`. The SDK will use the current session in the Twitter App if there is one, or it will fall back in a smart way. I can't say why your login is failing, but I would suggest simply removing it to get around the problem.

```
let composer = TWTRComposer()

composer.setText(tweetText)

composer.show(from: self.navigationController!) { (result in
    if (result == .done) {
        print("Successfully composed Tweet")
    } else {
        print("Cancelled composing")
    }
}
```

You said that you already set everything up, but I will give you an installation checklist, should you have missed a step:

- Initialize Twitter Kit

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"xxx", consumerSecret:"xxx")

      return true
   }
  ```
- Configure Info.Plist

  ```
  // Info.plist
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>twitterkit-<consumerKey></string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>twitter</string>
      <string>twitterauth</string>
  </array>
  ```

If you are still having problems, make sure to check your app's status at https://apps.twitter.com/. There are multiple ways of getting your app key restricted or even deactivated. If this is the case, there will be a red label underneath the app name.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem. I was using Twitter, FB and Google logins.
the problem in the plist sequence of he URLSchemes

I added twitter Schemes first it worked

my ex -

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>twitterkit-xxxx</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fbxxxxx</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxx-xxxx</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

In TwitterKit 3.3.0, [basically](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation):

> Although the callback URL will not be requested by Twitter Kit in your
>   app, it must be set to a valid URL for the app to work with the SDK.

even though when you try to create a [Twitter app](https://apps.twitter.com/) it doesn't say it is mandatory - **which it is** if you want below flow will work

**Failing to do that will break below entire flow and nothing will happen automatically:**

> If Twitter is not installed on the device it automatically falls back to use OAuth via a web view (using SFSafariViewController for the first user, and a UIWebView for subsequent additional users.)

**What will work if you *won't* have callback_url:**

Only if the user has Twitter app installed we can compose a twit or log-in - the rest just doesn't work.

When Twitter app **isn't** installed:

- When using `composer.show(from: self) { (result) in` you'll be getting `.cancelled`.
- When using `TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn(completion: { (session, error) in` you'll be getting `Request failed: unauthorized (401)`

**General notes:**

- If API key/secret are invalid, any action performed by TwitterKit lead to app crash
- Ensure that the singleton `start("key", "secret")` method, and project `plist` with the value: `twitterkit-{API KEY}` has the **same** key or else your app will crash.